# How to use LEFT+FIND combination inside FILTER+ARRAYFORMULA in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have the next data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b8BmHxUwLjk5DYbff77dd6O82Rl8EBsV3Rr2NCXpMug/edit#gid=2100307022

I need to count some metrics for each row in this table. Also I need to take into account three other properties. So, I chose the next formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF($C$206:$C$211 =" "; " "; SUM(FILTER(metric1; (property1="value1")*(property2="value2")*(property3=LEFT($C$206:$C$211; find(" "; $C$206:$C$211)-1))*(property4="value4")))); " - "))
```

It works perfectly beside the 3rd property condition. This condition is needed because I need only part1 from each of C206:C211 rows. As far as I could tell, the problem is with `LEFT` function as it can't be used this way with `ARRAYFORMULA`. But how do I fix this? I haven't found any suitable solution as I also have to keep all other conditions in filter.

Comment: You may use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) to create a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and add the expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow, thank you for your suggestion. I created the spreadsheet and tried to add some close-to-reality data. I added link to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=map(A6:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;sum(ifna(filter(data1!A:A;data1!B:B=B3;data1!C:C="low";regexextract(data1!D:D;"(.*?) ")=regexextract(Σ;"(.*?) ")))))))
```

[image]

Comment: I adjusted it to the original data and it worked perfectly! I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: with the way we are only looking at the first part of the *Property 3* (till first blank space); Is it an established fact that there's no chance of duplicates happening?! Like for e.g. in your sample dataset lets say we have *Lisa Bennett* & *Lisa Kudrow* but we are left with one unique *Lisa* when only first parts are considered...

Comment: No, that won't be a problem, because property3 consists only of one word. So using only `property3=regexextract(Σ;"(.*?) ")` is enough in my case.